# DB Transaction vs Java Thread

Tags: java, database, multithreading, transactions

My Question may be wrong. Forgive me.

I read the below example for deadlock while performing transaction.

Example:
In the student table, transaction T1 holds a lock on some rows and needs to update some rows in the grade table. Simultaneously, transaction T2 holds locks on some rows in the grade table and needs to update the rows in the Student table held by Transaction T1.

My Question is:

1. While using thread we can get deadlock, ok , but why deadlock is happening while using transaction?
2. Is transaction and java thread same? Please don't give definition!
3. Is transaction, DB related or Java program related?
4. Why we configuring @Transactional above method in your java code, if it is DB related?
5. Why DB using transaction instead of threads?
   Can any one give clear cut example.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Deadlock happens when two processes (or threads) are both trying to access locked data, and handle it in a way that prevents it from being unlocked. Locking access to data usually happens in a transaction, otherwise it makes no sense.

An example of such transaction:

```
1. transaction start
2.  lock grades for student A
3. Calculate average for the term
4. commit changes
5. end transaction - unlock data
```

1. No. A thread is a sub-process. For similicity sake, you may treat it as a separate program. A transaction is a database mechanism that allows you to perform several queries as one, with optional data locking, and to ensure that data is not changed between queries by another user or process (eg. another thread of your application)
2. Transaction is DB related.
3. To indicate that it deals with transactions
4. A thread is a concept of your program (java, etc.) A database is running on a server, for which every single query is isolated. A transaction is a database mechanism to ensure that data is consistent between queries and no other process modifies them in process.

An example.

Let us assume we are operating an online store with Products. A table Stocks holds amount of each product available in stock.

Imagine we have product A, for which we have exactly one in stock.

What happens without transactions:

- Customer 1 tries to order product.
- They check stock availability and start ordering process
- Meanwhile, customer 2 tries to order the same product. They see it as 'in stock' and start ordering.
- whoever pays first, gets their product, the other customer pays, and gets a 'sorry, the item was sold to another customer, we'll get back to you when it is available'

With transactions:

- Customer 1 starts ordering. The item stock is locked by a transaction, while the order takes place
- Customer 2 starts ordering. The transaction does not start until transacton 1 is complete. Then they see that the product is out of stock, WITHOUT ORDERING it.

The example may not be a real life (e-stores handle this in a different way), but to give you an idea how transactions work.

A more simple example is a counter, whose value is stored in a database. to increment a counter, you need to read its value first, and then add 'one' to it. If the counter is using transactions, all read attempts are queued or denied until an update is complete. without transactions, two processes may increment the same value, resulting in the counter being incremented once, not twice.